# Call method on Django fields

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Colour(models):
    ...
    def colour_preview(self):
        return format_html(...)


class ColourTheme(models):
    colour1 = models.ForeignKey(Colour)
    colour2 = models.ForeignKey(Colour)
    colour3 = models.ForeignKey(Colour)
    ...
    def preview(self):
        for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False):
            if (field.related_model == Colour):
                field.colour_preview()
```

I have a ColourTheme model with multiple Colour foreign keys, and I want to call a function on each of the Colour objects referred to by those fields.  The last line of code above fails. I would like to call colour_preview on all Colour fields without hardcoding them (`self.colour1.colour_preview()` works but not ideal).

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to the field in order to access related object method.

Try something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
class ColourTheme(models):
    colour1 = models.ForeignKey(Colour)
    colour2 = models.ForeignKey(Colour)
    colour3 = models.ForeignKey(Colour)
    ...
    def preview(self):
        for field in self._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False):
            if (field.related_model == Colour):
                field_obj = field.value_from_obj(self) # To get obj reference
                field_obj.colour_preview()
```